# restrict shipping of particluar item for paticular shipping zone

Tags: commerce

Is there a module available to restrict the shipping of the particular product for particular shipping zone(country)?
so that the message would appear and cancel the checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a field in variant for shipping restriction countries
2. Add a rule in with event Collecting shipping rates for an order
3. Add a php condition to get the line items details from $commerce_order
4. Check shipping restricted countries with shipping address countries in your php function
5. Remove the product by commerce_cart_order_product_line_item_delete()
6. Add an action to show the msg on site

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain there isn't a module that does this. You can build this with rules, but the effect will be very rudimentary.

Create a rule reacting to `order` updates:

1. Checks for a particular product included in the order.
2. Checks to see if a shipping address condition is met.
3. For your action, display a system message.
4. Set the status of the order to `cart` or perhaps `checkout:shipping`.

That way you wouldn't be able to advance past the shipping status without having it fulfilled.

Not knowing your situation, cancelling an order is a bit extreme, but you could forward the user to a webform, change the status of the order to some new, internal value for review, or even just remove the product from the cart so that the customer can continue.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
I am correcting it, I would prefer to remove that product from the cart so that the user can continue.